# Webpack & SignalR - помогите собрать для проекта на ASP NET Core

Tags: angular2, webpack, asp.net-core

В целях изучения SignalR, скачал один проект в сети, написанный на ASPNET Core, Angula2, SignalR.
В оригинале, там: npm, bower, сборщик gulp. Но в стандартном SPA шаблоне Angular2 для ASPNET Core, содержится только npm и Webpack. Захотелось мне перевести к этому виду все и тут началось...

Скачал SPA шаблон Angular 2 для ASP NET Core, отредактировал project.json, Startup.cs, package.json, добавил ts'ки. Запускаю Webpack и получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Типа не подключен JQuery и SignalR. Помогите пожалуйста заставить его работать.  [Ссылка на GitHub репозиторий](https://github.com/SolomatovS/Rox.Teleport)

Вот мой package.json

```js
{
  "name": "Teleport",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.10",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25",
    "bower": "1.7.9",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "signalr": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "less": "^2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.3",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

А вот оба конфига Webpack
Сначала webpack.config.js

```js
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "expose-loader?$!expose-loader?jQuery" },
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
        ]
    }
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
var clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist') },
    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : null,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
var serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [allFilenamesExceptJavaScript] })] // Don't bundle .js files from node_modules
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

Потом webpack.config.vendor.js

```js
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '', '.js' ]
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
            { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }
        ]
    },
    entry: {
        vendor: [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@angular/platform-server',
            'angular2-universal',
            'angular2-universal-polyfills',
            'bootstrap',
            'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'es6-shim',
            'es6-promise',
            'jquery',
            'zone.js',

            '@angular/upgrade',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api',
            'core-js',
            'reflect-metadata',
            'rxjs',
            //'systemjs',
            //'bower',
            'signalr'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        library: '[name]_[hash]',
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
            name: '[name]_[hash]'
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false } })
    ])
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Посмотри статью [ASP.NET Core, Angular 2, SignalR для чайников](https://habrahabr.ru/users/serginio1/topics/)

Главное это [ASP.NET Core + Angular 2 шаблон для Visual Studio](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/)

Там уже все настроено, нужно только добавить ссылки на SignalR

Ну и нужно задекларировать &

```
declare var $: any;
```

[Здесь рабочие реализации SignalR](https://github.com/Serginio1/Angular2SignalrCore/tree/master/Angular2SignalrCore/ClientApp/app/components/services)

Судя по https://github.com/SolomatovS/Rox.Teleport/blob/master/src/Teleport/ClientApp/app/components/shared/services/feed.service.ts
 $ не обявлена. Добавь `declare var $: any;` и будет тебе счастье

Comment: Проект основан на шаблоне asp net core + angular 2. В статье не описаны грабли, на которые натыкаешся при сборке signalr в webpack. особо не помог коммент

Comment: Там Webpack уже настроен. У тебя ошибка в коде смотри  declare var $: any; Посмотри весь код он есть по ссылке

Comment: Вот здесь рабочие реализации SignalR  https://github.com/Serginio1/Angular2SignalrCore/tree/master/Angular2SignalrCore/ClientApp/app/components/services

Comment: Прежде чем минуса ставить посмотри, что я тебе советую. Судя по https://github.com/SolomatovS/Rox.Teleport/blob/master/src/Teleport/ClientApp/app/components/shared/services/feed.service.ts $ не обявлена. А в моем сообщении уже в третий раз добавь declare var $: any; и будет тебе счастье